# Entity Framework / LINQ Round and Count Latitude/Longitude

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I'm working on a maps application and need to be able to pare down a giant dataset of location values into more reasonable values.  So what I'd like to do is group the positions by rounded values like the following SQL:

```
select ROUND(Latitude, 0), ROUND(Longitude, 0), count(*) from tweet
group by ROUND(Latitude, 0), ROUND(Longitude, 0)
order by count(*) desc
```

I can never get grouping to work the way I need it to though with EF and/or LINQ (mainly because I can't seem to understand how it works).  Ideally I would prefer to have it right in the EF query so that it becomes part of the SQL statement and I don't have to bring the giant dataset into a List before performing some LINQ operation on it...but if it has to be done that way then so be it.

I can do it this way, but I don't want to:

```
var items = context.ExecuteStoreQuery<DataPoint>("select ROUND(Latitude, 0) as lat, ROUND(Longitude, 0)as lon, count(*) as weight from location " +
"group by ROUND(Latitude, 0), ROUND(Longitude, 0) " +
"order by count(*) desc", null).ToList();
```

Edit:
Final solution (with a bit of back and forth) accepted below ended up looking like this:

```
private class DataPoint
{
  public double lat { get; set; }
  public double lon { get; set; }
  public int weight { get; set; }
}

var mydata = (from t in locations
group t by new { 
Latitude = EntityFunctions.Truncate(t.Latitude, accuracy).Value, 
Longitude = EntityFunctions.Truncate(t.Longitude, accuracy).Value } 
into g
orderby g.Count()
select new DataPoint{ lat =  g.Key.Latitude, lon = g.Key.Longitude, weight = g.Count() }).ToList();
```

Don't forget to add this using statement:

```
using System.Data.Objects;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from t in context.Tweets
group t by new { t.Latitude, t.Longitude } into g
order by g.Count() desc
select new { g.Key.Latitude, g.Key.Longitude, Count = g.Count() }
```

Comment: That's close but does not take into account rounding which is my main goal. Something like this would be close, but generates a runtime error:  `group t by new { Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(t.Latitude.ToString("##.#")), Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(t.Longitude.ToString("##.#")) } into g`

Comment: Specifically this error `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Double ToDouble(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`